# retrieving rows from a column in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a doubt to retrieve number of rows from a single column. So how can i retrieve only 5 rows from a single column randomly in sqlite3.

```
-(Question1*)readData1{
sqlite3_stmt *statement1;
int rowid1;
rowid1=[self getRowId1];

tempQuery=[@"select * from iapp_tbl_questions where id= " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid1]];


const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];  
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {


    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        vt=[[[Question1 alloc]init]autorelease];
        vt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,3)];

        NSLog(@"arr1 is %@",[vt.question description]);


    }
}


return vt;




-(int)getRowId1{    

sqlite3_stmt *statement1;
static int randomRowNum1;
BOOL isAvalible =NO;

if(table==1){
    query="SELECT * FROM 'iapp_tbl_questions' WHERE casenum = 16 order by RANDOM() Limit 1";
}
else if(table==2){
    query="SELECT * FROM 'iapp_tbl_questions' WHERE casenum = 15 order by RANDOM() Limit 1";
}

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        randomRowNum1=sqlite3_column_int(statement1,0);         
        break;                       
    }
}

for (int i=0;i<idStoreArray1.count;i++){
    NSString *rowidString1 =[idStoreArray1 objectAtIndex:i];
    if(rowidString1.intValue==randomRowNum1) {
        NSLog(@"rowidString1%@", idStoreArray1.count);
        //isAvalible=YES;
        //break;
    }       
}
if (!isAvalible) {
    [idStoreArray1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",randomRowNum1]];      
    NSLog(@"array count1----%@",idStoreArray1);
    NSLog(@"%d",idStoreArray1.count);
    return randomRowNum1;
}

else if(idStoreArray1.count < 6000){
    [self getRowId1];
    return randomRowNum1;
}
return 0;
```

Please let me know how can i get only 5 rows from a column in sqlite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also - the question isn't clear.  It doesn't capture why what you're doing isn't working.  Are you getting an error?  Are the results different than you expected?  It's not effective to state thinly what you're after, dump a batch of code and not cover what's wrong/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a set number of rows, then at the end of your SQL statement use the syntax:

```
LIMIT 5;
```

for example:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
FROM MyTable
LIMIT 5;
```